# Writing current file path in comment of file in Automator

Tags: bash, shell, path, posix, automator

I'm trying to write the current file path in the comment text box; the one you see when you right-click and Get Info. I'm pretty close, because I got it to write a file path to all the files inside a folder, but all the file paths are the same for some reason.

For example, when I right click a file after I run the script and see the comment, it might be "'/Users/Admin/Desktop/automator test/folder/spikyBall@2x copy 4.png'" and it will be that for all the files.

[image: Automator Workflow]

My Shell Script variable is defined as:

```
bashFilePath=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set filePath to quoted form of posix path of (item 1 of (get selection) as text)');

echo $bashFilePath;
```

Comment: I just figured out something vital. Even if I have a random number generated in place of the shell script, all the file's comments will be the same number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using pure Apple script for this. Select any files and folders that you want and run the script. It can also be made into a files or folders Service in Automator.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set fileList to selection

    if (count result) is 0 then
        try
            get (target of front Finder window) as alias
        on error
            choose folder with prompt "Set comments of files in this folder:"
        end try

        try
            set theFolder to result
            set fileList to every file of folder (result) as alias list
        end try
    end if

    display dialog "How would you like to set comments?" buttons {"Overwrite", "Cancel"} default button 2 with title "Set Spotlight Comments current to file path"

    set userInput to the result

    set itemNum to 1



    if (button returned of userInput) is "Overwrite" then
        if (class of first item of fileList) is alias then
            set comment of every file of folder theFolder to POSIX path of (item itemNum of (get selection) as text)
            set itemNum to itemNum + 1
        else
            repeat with thisFile in fileList
                set comment of thisFile to POSIX path of (item itemNum of (get selection) as text)
                set itemNum to itemNum + 1
            end repeat
        end if
    end if

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, try this:

```
echo $1
```

In shell scripts, `$1` is the first argument (`$2`, `$3`, etc. also work). So the above just echoes the first argument... which with your automator program is the path of the file.

Comment: Just echo $1? That puts nothing in the comments.